# How to get id of message that I reply to

Tags: node.js, discord.js, interaction

I have this command:

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from 'discord.js';
import { client } from '../index.js';
import * as functions from '../functions/functions.js';
// Creates an Object in JSON with the data required by Discord's API to create a SlashCommand
const create = () => {
  const command = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('pin')
    .setDescription('przypnij wiadomość na którą odpowiadasz');

  return command.toJSON();
};
const invoke = async (interaction) => {
  try {
    const message = interaction;
    await message.pin();
    console.log(`Pinned message ID: ${message.id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error pinning message:', error);
  }
};
export { create, invoke };
```

I'm stuck beacuse I want to get id of message for which I reply with this command. How I can get such a data from interacion? I'm looking for something simillar to `message.reference`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to fetch a message and pin it. There's no possible way to get a different `Message` from the interaction.

A simple way would be to use a `string` option to get the message ID, fetch the message in the current channel and then pin it.

```js
const create = () => {
    const command =
        new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('pin')
        .setDescription(
            'przypnij wiadomość na którą odpowiadasz'
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
            .setName('message')
            .setDescription('...')
            .setRequired(true)
        );

    return command.toJSON();
};
const invoke = async (interaction) => {
    try {
        const messageId =
            interaction.options
            .getString(
                'message');
        const message =
            await interaction
            .channel.messages
            .fetch(messageId);
        if (!message) return;
        await message.pin();
        console.log(
            `Pinned message ID: ${message.id}`
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            'Error pinning message:',
            error);
    }
};
```